# Should 1 Cor 14:2 say "by" or "unto"?

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians

Would not the dative translation "by" serve 1 cor 14:2 better than the word "unto"? In 1 cor 14:21 it can be seen that God gives this gift and speaks to us "with" or through people..

Comment: Brian (brmicke), I began writing my answer last night, but got sidetracked. When I finished it this morning, I was unable to reply due to the question being on hold. If you'd like the answer I wrote, please provide a method of contact. Also, if you'd like to ask more questions about Greek translations, please consider joining [the Greek language Stack Exchange project](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language?referrer=U9978Gdun72zfFj03568GA2).

Comment: @brmicke If you would like to include your contact info, you may do so in [your profile](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/20314/brmicke?tab=profile). Comments are not the place for that sort of thing. Thanks.

Comment: @RubelliteFae This question has been re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while we are waiting for Rubellite Fae, I'll give you my personal interpretation.

While it is true that in v. 21, we have God speaking to His people by means of people of other tongues, Paul proceeds from there to give direction about the use of foreign languages.

And, in v. 28, he says,

> But if there be no interpreter, let him keep silence in the church; and let him speak to himself, **and to God**.

Coming back to v. 2,

> For he that speaketh in an unknown tongue speaketh not unto men, but unto God: **for no man understandeth *him*; howbeit in the spirit he speaketh mysteries**. (KJV)

According to my notes, "him" is something of an interpolation of the grammar.

Now, it occurs to me that I should ask which "unto" you would change to "by" here.

As I read it, Paul takes up the subject of unknown tongues in this chapter and instructs the members to try to communicate with each other, rather than trying to sound cool or show how smart we are (vs. 15, 26).

Maybe the person speaking the foreign language understands him- or herself (v. 4), but the use of foreign languages in public meetings should be limited to those occasions when other people who speak the foreign language are present (v. 27).

Now, if changing one or both of the occurrences of "unto" in v. 2 to "by" helps you find a meaning that is overall consistent with the general instructions Paul is giving here, I'd say it may be useful to you.

I find that, when I am trying to talk with my wife and kids in Japanese and I screw up the grammar (as I often do), I am not speaking **by** God. God may know what I mean, but they do not. When I have patience to speak **to** God (pray in my heart) first, I am better able to speak **by** God, and I usually make fewer of the sort of mistakes that cause confusion and interfere with faith.

Comment: Although, I suppose, the expectation here is to refer to the source languages, and I have not done so. :-/

Answer (score 0):

> 1 Corinthians 14:2 For he that speaketh in an unknown tongue speaketh not unto men, but unto God: for no man understandeth him; howbeit in the spirit he speaketh mysteries. (KJV)

I have explored using the word " by" with a Greek expert. He told tell me that it is a valid concept, but that it would make no sense.

The reason He concluded that was that if both of the words translated as  "unto" we're translated as the words "by" then the portion you highlighted "for no man understandeth him" would be the reason for the speaking in tongues.

This is a very insightful observation that He made, albeit unknowingly. This can be clearly seen in Mark 4:12.

Jesus clear intention was to keep the knowledge of the kingdom away from those people who refuse to believe.

> Mark 4:12 That seeing they may see, and not perceive; and hearing they may hear, and not understand; lest at any time they should be converted, and their sins should be forgiven them.

In the Old Testament - The reason God initially spoke to the "drunken" priests in tongues was because they had previously been rebellious. For that reason God decided to speak to them in/with spiritual mysteries they could not understand,

> Isaiah 28:12 To whom he said, This is the rest wherewith ye may cause the weary to rest; and this is the refreshing: yet they would not hear

The stated purpose of God speaking through Isaiah was to cause the drunken priests to backslide, Isaiah 28:13.

> Isaiah 28:13 But the word of the LORD was unto them precept upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little; that they might go, and fall backward, and be broken, and snared, and taken.
>
> Matthew 13;12 For whosoever hath, to him shall be given, and he shall have more abundance: but whosoever hath not, from him shall be taken away even that he hath.

Comment: "The reason He concluded that was that if both of the words translated as "unto" we're translated as the words "by" then the portion you highlighted "for no man understandeth him" would be the reason for the speaking in tongues."
This isn't necessarily the case; even when the dative is rendered as instrumental, the final clause can be left off and the sentence makes sense, and "for no man understands" is an explanation of the foregoing clauses.

Comment: You.forget that in tje first NT explanation of Tongues in Acts, some of the "hearers" did understand that the.speakers were speaking of the "works of God".

Comment: Your argument is with Paul; he's the one who wrote "no man understands him".

Comment: No, some of the people in acts did understand that is a fact

Comment: You are missing the point , which is that " further study is indicated". We know the Bible does not contradict itself. Further study is a lot of work.